# How to replace tab navigation screen to stack navigation screen in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using stack navigation for the login module, When login is successful after that I navigate to the tab navigation (Home screen). When the user goes to log out from the profile screen after that I am not able to navigate on stack navigation (login screen).

I am searching on google but still have not found any related answer

this is the navigation screen code:-

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Navigation() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [sessionHandle, setSessionHandle] = useState(false);

  AsyncStorage.getItem('token', (err, result) => {
    setToken(result);
    if (!token) {
      setSessionHandle(false);
    } else {
      setSessionHandle(true);
    }
  });

  const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

  function MyTabs() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="HomeTab"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.black,
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: Colors.gray,
          tabBarStyle: {height: width * 0.18, borderRadius: 40},
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="HomeTab"
          component={ProductFlowNavigation}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarLabelStyle: {
              fontSize: 12,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
              marginBottom: 10,
            },
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
              const set_color = focused ? Colors.bright_sky_blue : Colors.gray;
              return <Ionicons name="ios-home" color={set_color} size={25} />;
            },
          }}
        />

        <Tab.Screen
          name="OrderHistory"
          component={OrderHistory}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'History',
            tabBarLabelStyle: {
              fontSize: 12,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
              marginBottom: 10,
            },
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
              const set_color = focused ? Colors.bright_sky_blue : Colors.gray;
              return <Ionicons name="timer" color={set_color} size={25} />;
            },
          }}
        />

        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={Profile}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
            tabBarLabelStyle: {
              fontSize: 12,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
              marginBottom: 10,
            },
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
              const set_color = focused ? Colors.bright_sky_blue : Colors.gray;
              return <Ionicons name="person" color={set_color} size={25} />;
            },
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }

  function MyLoginSignupNavigation() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Signup"
          component={SignUp}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={MyTabs}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {sessionHandle ? <MyTabs /> : <MyLoginSignupNavigation />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 0):

@mahesh you are switching between tab and stack navigation based on "`sessionHandle`", so i suggest you if you want to logout just set the value of "`sessionHandle`" to false, it will direct you to stack navigation first screen

```
{sessionHandle ? <MyTabs /> : <MyLoginSignupNavigation />}
```

you navigation depends on `sessionHandle`

Hopefully it will help you

Comment: thank you, Alok Singh, but my log-out function is on the profile screen not on the navigation screen. then how do I change the @sessionhandle  value on the profile screen

Comment: you can use redux or cotext api to manage state across the app @mahesh

Comment: I am using redux to manage state

Comment: then you can change the sessionhandle state through the redux.